# Start theorem counter from specific number

Tags: theorems, counters

I have defined a new theorem and I would like it to start from a specific number(let's say 3). At first I thought of using `\addtocounter{\theexe}{3}`(where *exe* is the new theorem) but I get an error stating that *No counter '0' defined*.

What I did next was to (re)define my counter using `\renewcommand*{\theexe}{0}` but I still get the same message. How can my counter be forced to start from 3. My code is

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\newtheorem{exe}{Problem}
\renewcommand*{\theexe}{0}

\begin{document}
\addtocounter{\theexe}{3}
\begin{exe}
This is the third problem
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`exe` is a LaTeX counter, and `\theexe` is a macro for formatting/displaying the current value of the counter (and is by default set to `\arabic{exe}`).

Redefining `\theexe` with `\renewcommand` will not change the underlying counter, and redefining it to always be `0` will cause all values of the counter to be displayed as zero.

Instead, you should be using the LaTeX counter commands, such as `\setcounter` and `\addtocounter`. While you have tried the latter, you tried passing the current display value of the counter instead of the name of the counter.

Note also that the `exe` environment automatically adds one to the counter (which starts off set to zero).

The correct syntax is `\setcounter{exe}{2}` (or `\addtocounter{exe}{2}`) to achieve that the number of the `exe` counter used in the first `exe` environment should be `3`. As Andrew Swann has pointed out, it's probably safter to use the `\setcounter` version as there will not be any issues in case the line is accidentally duplicated, whereas the `\addtocounter` version would act twice.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\newtheorem{exe}{Problem}
\setcounter{exe}{2}
\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
This is the third problem
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 but I would say it is safest to use `\setcounter{exe}{2}` e.g. if you include the code twice by mistake.

Comment: @AndrewSwann: Thanks for your comment. I have updated the answer to use that form in the main code, as was in fact my original intention (it was the one I mentioned in the text, albeit misspelt to begin with).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It is working!!! Thank's a lot!